# Very old GPU 2.82a blender viewport glitches. What version could work with hd4870? Is it really version problem? Has anyone seen anything like this?

Tags: versions

Hello i am trying to use blender 2.82a on ubuntu however i ran into strange graphical glitches not present in any other 3d program. They happen after i exceed certain amount of subdivisions and look like broken edges, loose lines that aren't there.
[image]

This is after subdividing basic cube face ~4 times with no other transformations.

My specs: Ubuntu 20.04, Radeon hd4870, intel core 2 duo e8400

Comment: Hello :). I'd start with [Blender 2.79](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) and then worked [down the list](https://download.blender.org/release/). The current 2.8 series mostly doesn't support GPUs earlier than 2013.

Comment: @JachymMichal Hey 2.79b works where 2.82a fails :) finally a solution shame UI is so different but oh well

Comment: Hello :). With respect, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because it's about supported hardware. Don't be discouraged and please keep the questions coming :).